# what may happen if the size of my git repo on github exceeds 1GB?

Tags: git, version-control, github, bitbucket, google-code

The following is from github:help, https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota:

my question is what will happen if the size of repo exceeds 1GB, **what may happen if I don't reduce its size?** (That is i just ignore that polite email, and can I push more files to my repo if the size of my repo exceeds 1GB)

> GitHub doesn't have any set disk quotas. We try to provide abundant 
>   storage for all Git repos, within reason. Keeping repos small ensures
>   that our servers are fast and downloads are quick for our users.
>
> **Rule of thumb: 1GB**
>
> For best performance, we recommend repositories be kept under 1GB
>   each.  This limit is easy to stay within if large files (typically,
>   binaries)  are kept out of the repo. If your repository exceeds 1GB,
>   **you might receive  a polite email from support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository  to bring it back down under 1GB**.

This issue is not the same as [How to reduce the size of a repo on Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596696/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-a-repo-on-github)

Also I know google code's limit on space quota is 4GB, what may happen if the size exceeds 4GB?

One more question, what is the disk usage quota of one repo for bitbucket?

Comment: You ... might ... receive ... à polite email? What sort of question is this?

Comment: @Tibo what will happen if i just ignore this email?

Comment: @hugemeow Does it matter?  Be a good citizen.   You're getting free stuff...try to help them out with providing it.  If you want more space, pay for it.

Comment: @cHao dude, sometimes a repo could be larger than 1GB:( just cannot reduce the size...

Comment: @hugemeow: It's a lot easier than you think.  Keep in mind, Git compresses the repo's contents.  Each revision takes up a pretty small amount of space.  For reference, the entire PHP repo, which includes most every non-suicidal version since 4.0 (about ~30 release branches) and a bunch of experimental branches, is <700 MB.  That's pretty freaking efficient.  Unless you're committing a bunch of binaries that change frequently, it's actually not quite that easy to surpass the limit.

Comment: @cHao maybe you are right, but it is also possible to have a git repo whose size is larger than 1GB, can github deal with such large git repos?

Answer (score 3):

> If your repository exceeds 1GB, **you might receive 
>   a polite email from support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository 
>   to bring it back down under 1GB**.

I think you answered your own question.

Comment: read my edits carefully, plz. what may happen if i don't reduce its size?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? Ask Github!