# Github repository hard limit

Tags: git, github

Ok so i made some changes to the firefox browser on my local machine and now i am trying to upload it on my repository at github.

However the writing objects process gets stuck exactly at 2gb. So is this some kind of limit on github repo size or is my broadband connection playing games with me.

In either case what are my options.

Comment: ummm isn't the link for file sizes and not repository sizes ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But there are lots of other questions and answers about overall repository size, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633603/what-may-happen-if-the-size-of-my-git-repo-on-github-exceeds-1gb