# Delete some commits from remote repository assuming I'm the only person working on it

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to free up memory space on my server's hard drive. I've huge amounts of repositories and would like to delete many commits from the repos. So I've been trying to do that with git rebase -i ~HEAD4, but I can't update the remote repo.

How should I proceed to delete some comits from origin master?

Thanks in advance
BEst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are sure of what you are ding, you can try a:

```
git push --force
```

In order to rewrite the history of SHA1 on the remote repo as well.

It won't work if your *remote* repo is explicitely configured to deny non-fast-forward merge or delete (as explained in this [blog post](https://joshua.hoblitt.com/rtfm/2013/02/preventing_git_nonfastforward_force_pushes/)):

```
git config receive.denyNonFastforwards true
git config receive.denyDeletes true
```

You would need to connect on the EC2 instance in order to change those, just for you to be able to force the push (and then restore the config).

As mentioned by [Michaël Witrant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188760/michael-witrant) [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378680/delete-some-commits-from-remote-repository-assuming-im-the-only-person-working/16378807#comment23474001_16378807):

> this will probably not actually free disk space until the garbage collector is run.
>   You should run `git gc --aggressive` on the server
>   (or `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` if it's a non bare repository)

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596696/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-a-repo-on-github

Comment: it didn't work. I receive this:
To gitolite@ec2.com:repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)

Comment: @user1098135 the settings on the remote repo might prevent that push: see my edit.

Comment: Note that this will probably not actually free disk space until the garbage collector is run. You should run `git gc --aggressive` on the server (or `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` if it's a non bare repository)

Comment: @MichaëlWitrant good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.